# F-statistics and paired t-test

Tags: anova, t-test, f-test

I want to create a synthetic data set with $n = 3$ replicates for each of $a = 3$ groups such that

1. the overall F - test rejects $H_0: µ_1 = µ_2 = µ_3$ at the $\alpha  = 0.05$ level,
2. but all three pairwise t-tests of the form $H_0 : µ_i = µ_j , i \ne j$ have p-values greater than $0.05$.

While reading this question, I cannot really come up with a good example. Is it ever possible? Intuitively, isn't the second condition negating the first condition?

I know of any other instances with more replicates that suffices this condition, but I somehow cannot do the same in 3 replicates.

Comment: What does "replicates" mean here? Usually when I hear replicates in stats, it refers to repeated measurements or clustered data.